# How to extend grid cell borders to bottom of Kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to have the cell borders on a Kendo grid extend to the bottom of the grid area even when there are not enough rows to reach the bottom of the grid area?

Comment: No it is not possible. You can not add empty lines.

Comment: not sure if you're also having the same issue, but this css will add a bottom border to the borderless last row:table[role~=grid] > tbody > tr:last-of-type > td
{
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

Comment: that looks much nicer, thank you!